# How to check if a numpy array holds a same value?

Tags: python, numpy

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86cmo.png)

[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVDu7.png)

i want to check if target has the same array of template has.

for example,

```
#The array of template
[[[162 181   0]
  [ 36  28 237]
  [  0   0   0]
  [100  60  52]
  [ 39 127 255]]

 [[162 181   0]
  [ 36  28 237]
  [  0   0   0]
  [100  60  52]
  [ 39 127 255]]

 [[162 181   0]
  [ 36  28 237]
  [  0   0   0]
  [100  60  52]
  [ 39 127 255]]]

#the array of target
[[[162 181   0]]

 [[162 181   0]]

 [[162 181   0]]]
```

so **if target has the same array** returns true

but if target has different value like below

```
[[[150 181 0]]

[[162 181  0]]

[[162 181  0]]]
```

it returns **False.** how would i be able to do so?

thinking of using numpy but i dont know how

Comment: Your attached pictures are too small for me to see.

Comment: `np.allclose(template[..., 0], target)`?

Comment: @吴慈霆 i attached the array of template and target images

Comment: @mozway i get ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,5) (3,1,3)

Comment: The template and the target array have different shapes. How do you want to perform the check in that case? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
any(((template[:, i, :] == target).all() for i in range(template.shape[1])))
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way.